# Case for table view cell. swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a `tableview` and I made  `cell.xib`. 
In these `tableview` there will be different `cell`s that I do the same with `xib`.

An example of how I use it.

```
 if indexPath.row == 0 {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: TableViewCellOne.identifier,
            for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellOne

        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
        }

if indexPath.row == 1 {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: TableViewCellTwo.identifier,
            for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellTWo

        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
        }
              return UITableViewCell()
        }
```

But I do not like this approach. How can I do this with `case`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using switch case as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0: //TableViewCellOne
                return 4
        case 1: //TableViewCellTwo                
                return 5                
        default:
                return 0
        }
    }
```

Then `cellforRow` method would be:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

switch indexPath.section {
     case 0:  //cell One
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: TableViewCellOne.identifier,
                for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellOne    
            return cell ?? UITableViewCell()

     case 1: //cell two
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: TableViewCellTwo.identifier,
                for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellTWo    
            return cell ?? UITableViewCell()

     default: 
             return UITableViewCell()
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write protocol `DequeueInitializable` and its extension like this

```
protocol DequeueInitializable {
    static var reuseableIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension DequeueInitializable where Self: UITableViewCell {

    static var reuseableIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }

    static func dequeue(tableView: UITableView) -> Self {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.reuseableIdentifier) else {
            return UITableViewCell() as! Self
        }
        return cell as! Self
    }
    static func register(tableView: UITableView)  {
        let cell = UINib(nibName: self.reuseableIdentifier, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cell, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.reuseableIdentifier)
    }
}

extension DequeueInitializable where Self: UICollectionViewCell {

    static var reuseableIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }

    static func dequeue(collectionView: UICollectionView,indexPath: IndexPath) -> Self {

       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.reuseableIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        return cell as! Self
    }
     static func register(collectionView: UICollectionView)  {
          let cell = UINib(nibName: self.reuseableIdentifier, bundle: nil)
          collectionView.register(cell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: self.reuseableIdentifier)
      }
}
```

Then confirm your cell with this protocol

```
class TableViewCellOne: UITableViewCell, DequeueInitializable {
}
```

then in your `cellForRow` method

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
   case 0:
    return TableViewCellOne.dequeue(tableView: tableView)
   case 1:
    return TableViewCellTwo.dequeue(tableView: tableView)
   default:
   return UITableViewCell()
}
```